# Disabling iCloud to Transfer App to Another Apple ID?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I am trying to transfer an app to another Apple ID. When I did this I received an error saying the app could not be transferred as the app had iCloud enabled.

Since this was not intentional I tried to disable iCloud and submit an update to the app. To do this I:

1. Changed the app ID in the Apple Dev Portal so that iCloud was no longer enabled.
2. Reissued all the certificates with the new app ID.
3. Made sure the Enable iCloud check box under summary in Project Info was not checked.

However I can still not transfer the updated app and am still getting the error that iCloud enabled apps cannot be transferred.

Does anyone know if this can be fixed - or is it a case of fully deleting the app and starting again?

Comment: Hi, I'm also have this problem and tried to fix this with an app update without iCloud just like you did. The documentation says you can't transfer an app if it has iCloud entitlements in **any version** of the app. How did you ended up fixing this? Or can anybody help us? I'm also going to contact Apple about this problem but they always take forever to respond.

Comment: Let me know if you get an answer - I never did :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I emailed with Apple and even spoke to the developer support about this issue. There is absolutely no way to transfer an app that uses or has used in a past version iCloud to another account.

This leaves you with these 2 options suggested by Apple:

1. Rename your complete iOS account, but this is only possible if your company has undergone a legal name change. Contact support if you want to do this.
2. Delete your app and free the app name and re-upload the app in your new account. You will lose the ability to update current users. https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35 (Deleting an App)

Too bad.

Comment: That is kind of lame... Thanks for the info though!

Comment: What happens if your company is acquired? Surely there some way of transferring it? If not, and your app looses all it's users, reviews etc, it's a complete deal breaker?

Comment: Answering my own question. I have spoken to Apple more than once on this matter now and there is NO way this can be done. Daniel's answer is still correct and up to date.

Comment: It's the year 2021 and I just experienced that this problem still exist. So sad.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update since this a VERY old answer. Deleting your app DOES NOT free your app name. On the contrary, it prohibits you from using that app name forever ON YOU OWN ACCOUNT ONLY. Other can use it but not on your account.